# Is it possible to find a 2x2 Hermitian matrix whose eigenvalues have 1:2 ratio?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, density-matrix, linear-algebra, stoquatic-matrices

Is it possible to find 2x2 Hermitian matrix whose eigenvalues have 1:2 ratio and if it is how is it done?

Comment: Hi there, on QCSE our focus in on quantum computation and quantum information, generic math question that may be more suited for MSE.

Comment: This is a generic math question that may be more suited for MSE

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This can be done for example by placing the desired eigenvalues along the diagonal

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

since all real diagonal matrices are Hermitian. More generally, for any desired eigenvalues $\lambda_k\in\mathbb{R}$ and any orthonormal basis $|k\rangle$, the matrix of the operator

$$
\sum_k\lambda_k|k\rangle\langle k|
$$

is Hermitian.

Comment: Rephrasing the same thing, let $Λ$ be a real-valued diagonal matrix whose entries have a 1:2 ratio. For any 2x2 unitary matrix $U$, the matrix $H\equiv UΛU^\dagger$ is a 2x2 Hermitian matrix whose eigenvalues have a 1:2 ratio.

Comment: Thanks.  Is it possible to find 2x2 Hermitian matrix with eigenvalues 1:2 ratio without zeros?

Comment: Almost all the matrices Adam and I have proposed won't have zeros. ^_^ As a simple example, let $U$ be the Hadamard matrix, and $Λ$ be the diagonal matrix in Adam's answer. Work out the matrix multiplication for $UΛU^\dagger$ and you'll have what you're looking for.